# Apresentando resultado de Regressão Linear Tabelada

Tags: r

Essa é a matriz com os resultados dos meus modelos de regressão:

```
linear_models=structure(c(-0.9051, 2.0445, 0.0075, 0, -3.9959, 7.4458, 0, 0, 
-0.0666, 0.4933, 0.8627, 0.4268), .Dim = c(2L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("(Intercept)", "complete.ini$idiff_3m.grb[-c(502:504)]"
    ), c("Estimate", "Pr(>|t|)", "Estimate", "Pr(>|t|)", "Estimate", 
    "Pr(>|t|)")))
```

O comando abaixo é usado para dar nomes a cada duas colunas dessa matriz. Eu tenho 3 nomes, portanto tenho 3 modelos.

```
names(dimnames(linear_models)) <- c("         Variables",
                                    "     (Model 1)     (Model 2)      (Model 3)")
```

Agora com a função print.char.matrix() do pacote Hmisc  eu faço o seguinte:

```
print.char.matrix(round(linear_models,4), col.txt.align = "left", col.names = TRUE,row.names = TRUE)

+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|                   Variables          |Estimate|Pr(>|t|)|Estimate|Pr(>|t|)|Estimate|Pr(>|t|)|
+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|(Intercept)                           |   -0.9051|   0.0075   |-3.9959|0|-0.0666|0.8627|
+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|complete.ini$idiff_3m.grb[-c(502:504)]|   2.0445 |   0        |7.4458 |0|0.4933 |0.4268|
+--------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Como podem ver não esta bem ajustado, além dos nomes dos modelos terem sido apagados:

O resultado que eu queria era esse:

```
+------------------------------------------+----First Model--+---Second Model--+---Third Model---+
    |                   Variables          |Estimate|Pr(>|t|)|Estimate|Pr(>|t|)|Estimate|Pr(>|t|)|
    +--------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
    |(Intercept)                           |-0.9051 | 0.0075 |-3.9959 |    0   |-0.0666 |0.8627  |
    +--------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
    |complete.ini$idiff_3m.grb[-c(502:504)]| 2.0445 |   0    |7.4458  |    0   |0.4933  |0.4268  |
    +--------------------------------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Pessoal, como faço esse ajuste? Há alguma função que faça isso pra mim?

Alguma ajuda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você irá precisar trabalhar um pouco a sua matriz, especialmente para colocar "Variables" pois ela não pertence nem ao `row.names` nem ao `col.names`, que são os argumentos utilizados pelas funções mais comuns. Após isso, basta escolher a sua função que tem maior familiridade (`knitr::kable`, `pander::pandoc.table`, etc):

```
linear_models <- as.data.frame(linear_models)
linear_models$Variables <- row.names(linear_models)
linear_models <- linear_models[, c(ncol(linear_models), 1:(ncol(linear_models)-1))]
names(linear_models) <- c("Variables", rep(c("Estimate", "Pr(>|t|)"), 3))
kable(linear_models, row.names = F) %>% 
  add_header_above(c("", "First Model" = 2, "Second Model" = 2, "Third Model" = 2))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Funciona tanto para PDF como para HTML. Se você está tentando gerar uma tabela no PDF tente também `stargazer`: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/vignettes/stargazer.pdf. Ao invés de entrar com o `linear_models`, você entraria com os 3 modelos em si, e a tabela é por conta dele.